# 2006 Solstice - car won't turn over following engine replacement

Tags: starting, pontiac, computer, gm, solstice-of-sorrow

I recently installed an engine (complete from oil pan to the valve cover) from a 2010 Malibu in my 2006 Solstice. (Replacing a blown engine.) The car will not crank / turn over.

Symptoms include:

- My scanner (HP tuners) reports no DTCs, and my CEL is not lit.
- No security light, though this was formerly lit when I had not properly reconnected the BCM connectors between the chassis/body harness and engine harness.
- Fuel pump is also not being activated
- When turning the key, I can hear relays clicking from the fuse block under/behind the passenger floorboard as well as from the fuse block in the engine bay.

Also,

- Lights work.
- Instrument cluster does it's POST thing when turning the key to "start" or "run." (Gauges sweep all the way to the right then back to zero. All lights are tested. DIC shows "Solstice" and then the odometer reading. (I would probably get a "ding ding" with the door opened if I had not removed the stock stereo, which I have not replaced.)
- Windshield wipers work. In fact, as far as I can tell, everything else works.
- There is +12V at the starter (tested with multimeter, and since the engine turns over when shorting (welding!) the starter posts.)

I lost the fuel pump relay, so moved the one for the electric trunk release into the fuel pump spot. They had the same part number and looked identical so I doubt this is the issue.

Car has a new battery (fully charged) and a new starter (properly connected). I can turn the engine over by shorting posts on the starter but, with no fuel, of course it won't start.

At one point when the security light was on (which I assume was just due to the BCM connector not being properly seated), I tried the 30 minute key relearn procedure, just before I found the BCM connector issue and fixed it. I don't suppose it's possible that the car is stuck in relearn mode following a week if sitting?

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed. If anyone has any suggestions, or a place where I can find a diagnostic flowchart for this car, I would be eternally grateful.

  -

Comment: That's an epic level of detail, good stuff!

Comment: Have you looked at the security system at all? Could be a start interrupt causing your no start issue. Maybe a blinking security light?

Comment: @Paulster2 no security light. :(

Comment: Is there a little lock light illuminated on the dash? It might look [like this](http://www.diy-gm-security.com/yahoo_site_admin/assets/images/Chevy_Security_Light_Amber.28510457_std.jpg).

Comment: When you replaced the engine, what did you do with the Engine control unit?

Comment: Using computer (ECU/ECM) and engine harness from the old setup. Both are ecotec  LE5. Only difference I saw was oil dip stock tube shape. (This engine is typically mounted for FWD, my car is RWD)

Comment: Oh: my car is a 5-speed, and the donor was an automatic. Put in an aluminum flywheel while I was at it.

Comment: I'll be back at the shop this weekend, can perform more tests then. Feel free to suggest your favorite hopefully-applicable diagnostic and I will most likely try it.

Comment: @MarkJohnson my partner-in-crime mentioned that the fuel pump wasn't firing. I'll investigate. Car is about 128 miles from here at the moment.

Comment: @paulster2 no. The security / lock light is not lit.

Comment: @DavidLively - No worries ... just making sure we were talking apples-to-apples here. Just one more security light question: Does the security dash light illuminate when you turn the key from off to on, then go out? If it doesn't come on at all, the light itself may be burned out and you aren't seeing it (I promise, this is the last TDM question I'll ask!!! :-)

Comment: @Paulster2 Please don't filter your questions! I am not offended! I agree that this sounds like a lockout of some kind. I'm heading up to the shop tonight (car is outside of Durant, OK and I live in Dallas) to give it another shot. The light illuminates during POST (power-on self test - a computer term, not sure what it would be called in car land), so I know it's alive. Wish I could see the startup conversation between the ECM and BCM. I wonder if HP Tuners (already have it) will do that. They said something about status bits, but I'm not a tuning expert.  Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: @DavidLively - POST works here as well. I'm not sure if HP Tuners will communicate over the CANBus to the BCM, but hopefully it will. It might give you some insight into what's going on. Only other thing I can think of is a starter relay issue, but that wouldn't account for the lack of fuel pump action (unless it's already primed). You may put a fuel pressure gauge on the Schraeder valve and see what you have there. You may be surprised. Usually, if it isn't turning over and there's no fuel pump, it has something to do with the TDM.

Comment: @Paulster2 that's my thinking as well, or possibly clutch pedal sensor. Wish I could just bypass the TDM. It's a track car - if someone manages to steal it out of my garage they probably deserve to have it.

Comment: @DavidLively - Hadn't thought of the clutch sensor. That would be easy to jump and check to make sure.

Comment: @Paulster2 found the status bits in HP tuners. P/N clutch changes when I press the pedal, so I guess the sensor is working. (Can also see signal at the relay.) still no crank. Oddly enough, the "clutch state" bit always shows "in." Looking for. Way to bypass the TDM for testing.

Comment: It's alive! Engine bay fuse box connectors were not seated properly. Got removed during the swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well:

When I reinstalled the engine harness and connected it back to the engine bay fuse block, I didn't properly tighten the five bolts that secure the connectors to the fuse panel. Apparently it was therefor not correctly grounded.

Yay. Thanks everyone for the help![image: muahaha]